# Mark as duplicate, original being deleted and unconsistent dialog showing

Tags: support, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, close-dialog

I just saw this question: [using sed command grab lines between n blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22453448/using-sed-command-grab-lines-between-n-blocks) that had been posted by the same user one hour ago.

I marked as duplicate, but then the OP deleted the original, so now this is what shows off when I click the "close" button:

> [image]

Without any way to "Retract close vote". Is this the expected behaviour or should my vote to close be reverted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your close vote got automatically cleared by Community when the other question got deleted. Looks like, since the other question is no longer a valid duplicate target, it just cleared out your vote since the question can't be closed for that anymore.

It makes sense for the system to do that (and I wasn't aware that it did, I'm just reading the timeline).

Comment: But shouldn't it delete the "you have already voted to close" message and make me able to vote to close again (if needed)?

Comment: No. There are no circumstances where you're able to vote again or change your vote. Once you've cast your vote, you're done.